# Install subversion client version 1.8 for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I need to install subversion client with version something like 1.8. But I need it for ubuntu 16.04. In current repos version is obviously higher.

I tried to to find some sources or repos with needed version but I can't found abything useful except for few someonse private repos.
Where can I find and install svn 1.8 client for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Get the source package from a previous version (`apt-get source subversion=<exact version number>`), install required libraries ( `apt-get build-dep subversion`) then build yourself with `dpkg-buildpackage`. You'll get a subversion-xx.deb, so `dpkg -i subversion*deb`.

Comment: ubuntu says that I should place sorces URI into sources.list. Tried to add `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/svn/ppa/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/svn/ppa/ubuntu precise main 
` but there is no change.

Comment: `deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main`